# notebook fails to start frequently but sometime it works great

Tags: motherboard, bios, power, vga, post

-cpu and ram test and stress test pass when works
-bios reset or load default setting didn't work
-disconnecting every components and taking out mobo again no luck (only posts sometime)
-no luck with external monitor too
-alt+ctrl+del applied during post results ok on most cases but fails mostly if I turn off and power on again.
-without cmos, replacing cmos, pressing power button up to 1 min didn't help.

what could be the problem? MOBO? if which section?

Comment: Thank you for giving information on what you're tried, but you haven't described the actual problem yet:
What happens when you press the power button and it doesn't work? Do you see any indicator lights come on? Does the screen flicker? Do you hear the hard drive or fan come on? Does it just sit like a brick with no lights, no sound, no action?

Comment: power led turns on, fan spins but no display, no keyboard response like num lock caps lock don't turn on but as usual blinks once when power button pressed to turn on.